# Calling performSegueWithIdentifier on parent view from child doesn't change view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have a searchController and it has a searchResultsController. When I search in the search bar the results controller shows the search results, but when I tap on one of the cells it doesn't show the detail view controller. To get it to show, I have to hit the cancel button beside the search bar and when the searchResultsController disappears, the detail view appears. I know the perform segue function is being called on the parent view from the child view. The delegates for the tableview of the searchResultsController are all pointing to the searchController.

Why is the view not changing until I hit the cancel button?

Here's some of the code:

Search controller class:

```
// parent view controller
- (void) showContact:(Contact*)contact
{
    NSLog(@"Did tap contact id:[%@]",contact.id);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"contactPressed" sender:contact];
}

- (void)contactsSearchTableDelegate:(ContactsSearchTableDelegate *)delegate
                  didTapContact:(Contact *)contact
{
    [self showContact:contact];
}
```

Delegate Class:

```
// delegate, searchController and searchResultsController both point here
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.delegate contactsSearchTableDelegate:self didTapContact:[self contactAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search results controller is a *presented* view controller. Its view covers the screen and replaces the view of the view controller we started with. Thus, that view controller's view is not in the view hierarchy and we can't go anywhere from it. Thus, your code needs to do what you are doing manually now: it needs to start by cancelling the search and thus dismissing the presented view controller, so that we are back to the first view controller and can proceed from there.

Comment: But in this case, if we go back from the detail view, we're not going to go back to the search, we'll go back to the entire list. How do I preserve that functionality? Specifically going back to the search with whatever text they'd typed in and whatever search results?

Comment: I guess I've never envisioned an architecture such as you must have. I usually have a main view controller with a search bar in it, and when the user searches, the search controller presents its view with the search results controller. So there are only two views: the plain table, and the filtered table showing the results of the search. You have some _third_ view controller in the story? I'm not able to imagine that. Can you describe in more detail what you're doing?

Comment: No I don't have a third view controller. I have exactly what you said. But when the user taps on one of the cells in the search results, a new view is supposed to pop up with the details of that cell (i.e. contact information). But this doesn't happen, the view only pops up if I hit the cancel button beside the search bar.

Comment: Okay, so let's call the two view controllers Main and Search. Which view controller does the "contactPressed" segue come from and what kind of segue is it?

Comment: The contactPressed segue comes from the Main view controller. It's a push segue.

Comment: Well, there's your problem, _exactly as my answer said_. You cannot segue from Main until you get back _to_ Main. That means you must dismiss the search view controller, just as I said.

Comment: Yea I get that haha. So I guess the functionality I'm looking for is calling the push segue from the search controller instead of main, that way it will go back to the search controller when I press back and it should show the detail view when the cell is selected. Thank you!